# Python TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
, line 53, in draw_dots_in_circle
    x, y = get_random_location()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I've been working on this for hours and hours and need help.  All I need it to do is the count and make my ten dots.  Below is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
from random import randint

from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawLine
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import writeText
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawPoint
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawCircle
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawRectangle

y = random.randint(-125,100)
x = random.randint(-50, 50)

get_random_location = (x, y)


drawRectangle(x, y, 60, 40)

drawCircle(x, y, 80)

def is_point_in_square(x, y):
    if -125 <= x <= -25 and -50 <= y <= 50:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def draw_dots_in_square(x, y):
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        x, y = get_random_location()
        if is_point_in_square(x,y):
            drawPoint(x, y)
            count += 1



def is_point_in_circle(x, y):
    d = ((x - 50) ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5
    if d <= 50:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def draw_dots_in_circle(x, y):
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        x, y = get_random_location()
        if is_point_in_circle(x,y):
            drawPoint(x, y)
            count += 1

def main():
    print (draw_dots_in_circle(x, y))
    print (draw_dots_in_square(x, y))

main()
```

Comment: In my case was a comma in wrong place. I found it in this link https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-tuple-object-is-not-callable/

Answer (score 1):

Change `x, y = get_random_location()` to:

```
x, y = get_random_location
```

The error is pretty obvious. `get_random_location` is a tuple. You're trying to call it.

Nevertheless, I think what you intend to express is:

```
def get_random_location():

    y = random.randint(-125,100)
    x = random.randint(-50, 50)

    return x, y
```

Then you may call it as you want

```
x, y = get_random_location()
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @raulferreira that you probably want `get_random_location` to be a function rather than a variable.  But there are other problems with your code that will keep it from working:

- How is `is_point_in_circle()` going to work if it doesn't know the
  radius of the circle or what the point is?  (Or if it knows the
  point, then where the circle is?)
- Ditto for `is_point_in_square()` with respect to actual height and
  width.

My rework of your code with my best guess as to what the fuctions in UsefulTurtleFunctions.py do:

```
import turtle
from random import randint

from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawPoint
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawCircle
from UsefulTurtleFunctions import drawRectangle

def get_random_location():
    x = randint(-50, 50)
    y = randint(-125, 100)

    return x, y

def is_point_in_rectangle(x, y):
    rx, ry = rectangle_location

    return rx - rectangle_width/2 <= x <= rx + rectangle_width/2 and ry - rectangle_height/2 <= y <= ry + rectangle_height/2

def draw_dots_in_rectangle(x, y):
    count = 0

    while count < 10:
        x, y = get_random_location()

        if is_point_in_rectangle(x, y):
            drawPoint(x, y)
            count += 1

def is_point_in_circle(x, y):
    cx, cy = circle_location

    d = ((x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2) ** 0.5

    return d <= circle_radius

def draw_dots_in_circle(x, y):
    count = 0

    while count < 10:
        x, y = get_random_location()

        if is_point_in_circle(x, y):
            drawPoint(x, y)
            count += 1

x, y = get_random_location()
rectangle_location = (x, y)
rectangle_width, rectangle_height = 60, 40

drawRectangle(x, y, rectangle_width, rectangle_height)

x, y = get_random_location()
circle_location = (x, y)
circle_radius = 80

drawCircle(x, y, circle_radius)

draw_dots_in_circle(x, y)
draw_dots_in_rectangle(x, y)

turtle.done()
```

Adjust as the reality of your assignment demands.

[image]